# Prove that $2222^{5555}+5555^{2222}=3333^{5555}+4444^{2222} \pmod 7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, modular-arithmetic

I am utterly new to modular arithmetic and I am having trouble with this proof.

$$2222^{5555}+5555^{2222}=3333^{5555}+4444^{2222} \pmod 7$$

It's because $2+5=3+4=7$, but it's not so clear for me with the presence of powers.

Maybe some explanation would help.

**EDITED** Some serious typo

**EDIT**
Since some arguments against it appear here is :
[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%284444%5E5555%2B3333%5E2222+mod+7%29+%2C+%282222%5E5555%2B5555%5E2222+mod+7%29)

**EDIT** Above is incorrect. I appreciate proofs that it is wrong. Sorry for others.

Comment: `It's because 2+5=3+4=7`. That is not at all obvious to me.

Comment: some serious flaw.. is it still not because of that?

Comment: That's my guess though. I mentioned, I am utterly new.

Comment: One obvious thing to do is to simplify the bases modulo $7$, because $a \equiv b \bmod 7$ implies $a^n \equiv b^n \bmod 7$.

Comment: A less obvious thing to do (but it becomes obvious with more experience) is to simplify the exponents modulo $6$, because $a^{\varphi(7)} \equiv 1 \bmod 7$ when $\gcd(a,7) = 1$, and so $a^{\varphi(7) x + y} \equiv a^y \bmod 7$.

Comment: even though that was typo and not intended $$2222^{5555}+5555^{2222}=3333^{5555}+4444^{5555} \pmod 7$$ is still correct.

Comment: @Hurkyl is $a=b \mod 7 \implies a^n=b^n \mod 7$ one way implication or is it both ways i.e. is $a^n=b^n \mod 7 \implies a=b \mod 7 $?

Comment: The problem that you put into Wolfram Alpha and the problem that you posted here are different.

Comment: @700resu: In the original question, typo and all, both sides are easily congruent to $0$. With the change, that is no longer true. (Alpha is irrelevant, a glance shows it is true.)

Comment: I made a total mess. Terribly Sorry all. I appreciate proofs that it is incorrect.

Comment: Well, the last version of the question (local time: 04:40, 6/4/2013) is *not* what I tried to answer to...*sigh*...Oh, well.

Comment: @700resu: It is largely the question-setter's fault. Having all those $2222$ and $5555$ invites misreading.

Comment: @700resu: Consider $n=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First recall that as $7$ is prime, then $x^6 = 1 \pmod{7}$. Now, we have
$$ 2222 = \begin{cases} 2 \pmod{6} \\ 3 \pmod{7} \end{cases}, \quad 3333 = 1 \pmod{7}$$
$$4444 = -1 \pmod{7}, \quad 5555 = \begin{cases} 5 \pmod{6} \\ 4 \pmod{7} \end{cases}$$
Then we can reduce each side of the equation to 
$$ 3^5 + 4^2 = 1^5 + (-1)^2 \pmod{7}$$
Then the LHS is $0$ but the RHS is $2$, so the statement is false.

EDIT: For reference, I'm testing the conjecture $2222^{5555} + 5555^{2222} = 3333^{5555} + 4444^{2222}$.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct: how the huge exponent $\,5555\,$, for example, is shrinked to $\,5\,$ ?

Comment: Because $x^6 = 1 \pmod{7}$ for all $x$, so we can reduce all the exponents to their value mod $6$.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong: $x^6\not\equiv 1 \pmod 7$ when $x\equiv 0 \pmod 7$, not that it is relevant in this particular case.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you did, @ChristopherA.Wong: you worked *also* modulo $\,\phi(7)=6\,$...

Comment: @HenningMakholm, ah yes, I forget about that sometimes. While it didn't matter in this case, I had actually forgotten myself.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can change it to $3^{5555} + 4^{2222} \equiv 1^{5555} + 6^{2222} \pmod{7}$.

Then, notice that $3^6 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$, $4^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$, and $6^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$. You can shrink the exponents to $3^5 + 4^2 \equiv 1 + 1 \pmod{7}$

From there, it's just computation:
$$3^5 + 4^2 \equiv 1 + 6^0 \pmod{7}$$
$$243 + 16 \equiv 2 \pmod{7}$$
$$259 \equiv 2 \pmod{7}$$
$$0 \not\equiv 2 \pmod{7}$$

So it's false after all (I misread the exponents at first, sorry).

Since you're new to modular arithmetic, this may not be clear, but for all $x \ne 0$, $x^6 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$. See [Euler's totient theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem).

EDIT: Wow I'm sloppy today. Sorry. :\

Comment: You seem to believe that $\,2222=1\pmod 7\,$ but this is not so: $\,2222=3\pmod 7\,$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio: How do you infer such a belief? As far as I can see the $2222$ as a base does correctly become 3 -- on the other hand, the $2222$ exponent is correctly reduced to $2$ (modulo 6).

Comment: By looking to the first equation, @HenningMakholm: I'm trying to understand where that $\,1^{5555}\,$ on the right hand came from...

Comment: Of course, my belief is reinforced by the fact that I got a "true" value to the OP's claim, whereas Henry got a false one. Clearly, *at least* one of us is wrong...and by the life of me it could be myself.

Comment: @DonAntonio: $1^{5555}$ comes from $3333^{5555}$ in the question, and $3333=476\times 7 + 1$.

Comment: Oh, I see: he wasn't reproducing the OP's equation but actually equating the left and right sides. Thanks...still, he writes only $\,3\,$ and not $\,3333\,$ on the left hand....

Comment: And still-still: one line before the end of the calculations , why from $\,243+16=0\pmod 7\,$ he passes to $\,259\neq 2\pmod 7\,$ ?? In fact, $\,243+16=259=0\pmod 7\,$ !

Comment: @DonAntonio: Why should there be any $3333$ on the _left_ side? There we had $2222^{5555}$ which becomes $3^{5555}$ when we reduce the base modulo 7. (But you're right that the part of the answer _after_ that first line becomes hard to follow).

Comment: I think he (or I, in my mind) mixed both sides and that's causing some confussion here.

Comment: Yeah, at the end, I mixed both sides. But it should be cleared up now.

Answer (score 0):

$$2222=11\cdot202=22\cdot 101=101\pmod 7\\5555=11\cdot505=55\cdot 101=-101\pmod 7\\3333=11\cdot 303=33\cdot 101=(-2)\cdot 101\pmod 7\\4444=11\cdot404=44\cdot 101=2\cdot101\pmod 7$$

Well, now add modulo $\,7\,$ both sides of your equation...:)

**Added:** By the way, note that $\,101=3\pmod 7\,$ , so again doing arithmetic modulo $\,7\,$ we indeed get

$$\begin{align*}2222&=&3\\5555&=-3=&4\\3333&=-2\cdot 3=-6=&1\\4444&=2\cdot 6=&-1\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

See cycles.

1. $2222^6 \equiv 1\pmod{7}$ and $5555\equiv 5\pmod{6}$ then $2222^{5555}\equiv 2222^5\pmod{7}\equiv 5\pmod{7}$
2. $5555^3 \equiv 1\pmod{7}$ and $2222\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ then $5555^{2222}\equiv 5555^2\pmod{7}\equiv 2\pmod{7}$

left hand $= 5 + 2 \equiv 0\pmod{7}$

1. $3333^1 \equiv 1\pmod{7}$ and $5555\equiv 0\pmod{1}$ then $3333^{5555}\equiv 3333^1\pmod{7}\equiv 1\pmod{7}$
2. $4444^1 \equiv 1\pmod{7}$ and $2222\equiv 0\pmod{1}$ then $4444^{2222}\equiv 4444^1\pmod{7}\equiv 1\pmod{7}$

right hand $= 1 + 1 \equiv 2\pmod{7}$

$2222^{5555}+5555^{2222}=3333^{5555}+4444^{2222} \pmod 7$ is incorrect.

You can check with bc program:

```
bc 1.06.95
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'. 
2222^5555 % 7
5
5555^2222 % 7
2
3333^5555 % 7
1
4444^2222 % 7
1
```